# Selenium in google colab stopped working showing an error as Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, chromium

Few hour ago my setup in google colab for selenium worked fine. Now it stopped working all of a sudden.
This is a sample:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I get the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Any ideas on solving it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...implies that the chromedriver service unexpectedly exited.

This is because of the of an issue induced as the colab system was updated from `v18.04` to ubuntu *`v20.04 LTS`* recently.

The main reason is, with Ubuntu *`v20.04 LTS`* [google-colaboratory](/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) no longer distributes **chromium-browser** outside of a snap package.

---

### Quick Fix

> > `@mco-gh` created a new notebook following `@metrizable`'s guidance
> > (details below) which is working perfect as of now:
> > https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC

---

### Solution

As a solution you can install a compatible version of *`chromium-browser`* from the Debian buster repository using the following code block published by `@metrizable` in the discussion [Issues when trying to use Chromedriver in Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1387453484)

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. It still does not works. I get an error ""WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6""

Comment: On executing the suggestion i get an error : gpg: cannot open '/dev/tty': No such device or address

Comment: @БеляковаАнастасия Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: The code from this notebook worked https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC. Thank you! @undetected Selenium

Comment: The code snippet mentioned in the answer didn't work for me and I can't access the colab linked in the comments :( Is there a new update to colab after this workaround was established?

Comment: solved this problem? The code not work for me.