# Selenium on Colab

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I want to run selenium for image scrapping on Google Colab.
But I heard that I can't make it since this January.
So I found this([Selenium in google colab stopped working showing an error as Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75164313/selenium-in-google-colab-stopped-working-showing-an-error-as-service-chromedrive)) and it works for me.
And I send the code to my colleague but she said she couldn't run the code.

This is my code. And a picture shows error message.
What's the problem?

Thank you for reading and answering.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AePXa.png)

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

import sys

!sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
!sudo apt remove chromium-browser
!sudo snap remove chromium
!sudo apt install chromium-browser

!pip3 install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin/

sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

I have found 'Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1' and tried to fix my code according to searching results but it doesn't work.